# Testing for a low number BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to add a 0 in front of single digit numbers, the numbers are from 1-15. If the number is less than one then can it just ignore it. When I run this it just crashes saying 10 is not expected at this time. I am positive this method is terrible.

```
if %slide1% lss 10 set slide1=0%R1%
if %slide2% lss 10 set slide2=0%R2%
if %slide3% lss 10 set slide3=0%R3%
if %slide4% lss 10 set slide4=0%R4%
if %slide5% lss 10 set slide5=0%R5%
if %slide6% lss 10 set slide6=0%R6%
if %slide7% lss 10 set slide7=0%R7%
if %slide8% lss 10 set slide8=0%R8%
if %slide9% lss 10 set slide9=0%R9%
if %slide10% lss 10 set slide10=0%R10%
if %slide11% lss 10 set slide11=0%R11%
if %slide12% lss 10 set slide12=0%R12%
if %slide13% lss 10 set slide13=0%R13%
if %slide14% lss 10 set slide14=0%R14%
if %slide15% lss 10 set slide15=0%R15%
if %slide16% lss 10 set slide16=0%R16%

echo %slide1% %slide2% %slide3% %slide4%
echo %slide5% %slide6% %slide7% %slide8%
echo %slide9% %slide10% %slide11% %slide12%
echo %slide13% %slide14% %slide15% %slide16%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution to get a two digits number with a leading `0` for the numbers `1` to `9`:

```
@echo off
set "Number=1"

:Loop
set "TwoDigitNumber=0%Number%"
set "slide%Number%=%TwoDigitNumber:~-2%"
set /A Number+=1
if %Number% LSS 17 goto Loop

echo %slide1% %slide2% %slide3% %slide4%
echo %slide5% %slide6% %slide7% %slide8%
echo %slide9% %slide10% %slide11% %slide12%
echo %slide13% %slide14% %slide15% %slide16%
```

The current number is assigned as string to environment variable `TwoDigitNumber` with a leading `0` independent on the numbers value.

Then the last two characters of `TwoDigitNumber` are assigned as string to the target environment variable.

The exit of batch processing (no crash) with the error message

> 10 is not expected at this time

was caused most likely by a line on which any `%slideX%` expands to nothing because the environment variable `slideX` is not defined at all resulting in the invalid command line:

```
if lss 10 set slide1=01
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: Sure. `Number` and `TwoDigitNumber` in this demo batch code are just examples. It is also possible to use for example `set "slide1=0%R1%"` and on next line `set "slide1=%slide1:~-2%"`. `slide1` can be also `R1` in those two lines. A single line is also possible like `set "R1=0%R1%" & call set "R1=%%R1:~-2%%"`

Comment: Would it be shorter to just use letters instead?